# Estoy trabajando en una página web y utilizo php y JavaScript, no hace la eliminación del registro

Tags: php, javascript, crud

Estoy trabajando en una página web y utilizo php y JavaScript, soy nuevo en programación, estoy manejando un menú CRUD para varias tablas, pero al momento de hacer el método Delete no hace la eliminación del registro, este es el codigo que manejo:

//Este es mi boton

```
<button  id="delete-contrato-modal" name="delete-contrato-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-danger btn-just-icon remove"><i class="material-icons" data-target="#myModalDelete"  data-toggle="modal"
                    onclick="deleteCbContrato('<?php echo($row_herramientas['id_tipo_contrato']); ?>');">close</i></button>
```

// Este es el formulario

```
     function deleteCbContrato(id_tipo_contrato){     
            document.formDeleteContrato.id_tipo_contratoDelete.value = id_tipo_contrato;                

            $('#myModalDelete').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#myInput').focus()
            });

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST["delete-contrato-select"]) ) { 
            $idContratoSelect = $_POST['id_tipo_contratoDelete'];
            $cbContratoController->delete($idContratoSelect);
    }

    ?>

<div style="min-width: 200px !important;" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div  class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div  class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <button style="border-bottom-color: : none !important; box-shadow: none !important;"  class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="card "  >
                <div class="card-header card-header-rose card-header-icon">
                  <div class="card-icon">
                    <i class="material-icons">add_box</i>
                  </div>
                  <h4 class="card-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Contratos</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body ">


              <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">

<div class="row">
<label class="col-md-3 col-form-label"> ID </label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="form-group has-default">

              <input class="form-control"   type="text" name="id_tipo_contrato" id="id_tipo_contrato" placeholder="Escriba el id del contrato" title="Se necesita un ID. Ejemplo: un numero" pattern="[0-9]+" required/><br/><br/>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<label class="col-md-3 col-form-label"> TIPO DE CONTRATO </label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="form-group has-default">


          <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="tipo_contrato" id="tipo_contrato" placeholder="Escriba el nombre del contrato" title="Se necesita un nombre ejemplo:   
          CONTRATISTAS" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" required/><br/><br/>
              <input type="submit"  name="submitC" value="Agregar"/>

       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>





// Manejo un modal para mandar un mensaje cuando se quiera eliminar el registro

<!-- Modal DELETE -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalDeleteLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalDeleteLabel">Eliminación de Registro</h4>
                    </div>
                    <form role="form" name="formDeleteContrato" method="post" action="contratos.php">
                        <div class="modal-body">                                    
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label for="id_tipo_contrato">¿Desea eliminar el registro seleccionado?</label>
                                </div>       
                                <div class="input-group">
                                 <label for="id_tipo_contrato">Registro </label>
                                 <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="id_tipo_contratoDelete" name="id_tipo_contratoDelete" >                                        
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button id="delete-contrato-select" name="delete-contrato-select" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>                                        
                                <button id="cancel"type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>   



                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

//Tengo un controlador donde van las funcion de DELETE

```
<?php
class CbContratoController {

 var $conex = null;
        }


function delete($id_tipo_contrato){ 
    $sqlDelete = 
        "DELETE FROM tipo_contrato"
        . "     WHERE   id_tipo_contrato = '".$id_tipo_contrato."'"; 

}


?>
```

//Tambien manejo un java script que abro el modal donde pregunta si se quiere borrar el registro

```
 function deleteCbContrato(id_tipo_contrato){     
        document.formDeleteContrato.id_tipo_contratoDelete.value = id_tipo_contrato;                

        $('#myModalDelete').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myInput').focus()
        });
```

//Junto con el javascript manejo un if para ejecutar mi controlador con la funcion DELETE

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["delete-contrato-select"]) ) { 
        $idContratoSelect = $_POST['id_tipo_contratoDelete'];
        $cbContratoController->delete($idContratoSelect);
}

?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a SOe. Deberías acotar un poco la pregunta; ¿dónde falla? ¿Al visualizar una página web? ¿Al ejecutar un PHP? ¿Cuál, y a ser posible, en qué línea?. Y ¿cuál es el fallo? ¿No te responde? ¿Te muestra un error? ¿Parece que funciona pero no hace te borra el registro?

Comment: No marca error, simplemente no hace la eliminación del registro que deseo eliminar, es como si no obtuviera el id del contrato

Comment: Empieza a depurar, por ejemplo, imprime la variable `$sqlDelete` con un simple `echo $sqlDelete;`. De entrada, si la columna es numérica, tu consulta está mal escrita. En cualquier caso, copia la consulta que se imprima y pruébala directamente en el manejador de base de datos.

Comment: Al tratar de imprimir la variable me aparace este error  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: Pon el código que intentaste. ¿No olvidaste de poner el `;` verdad? Es aquí donde deberías empezar a depurar: **`function delete($id_tipo_contrato){ 
    $sqlDelete = 
        "DELETE FROM tipo_contrato"
        . "     WHERE   id_tipo_contrato = '".$id_tipo_contrato."'";  echo $sqlDelete;

}`**

Comment: No no lo olvide, cheque la consola y me aparece este error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteCbContrato is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick

Comment: Si no me mencionas no puedo leer el comentario. El `onClick`  está fuera, deberías ponerlo dentro del botón, por eso no lo está llamando. Debes ponerlo así en el HTML: **`<button  id="delete-contrato-modal" name="delete-contrato-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-danger btn-just-icon remove" onclick="deleteCbContrato('<?php echo($row_herramientas['id_tipo_contrato']); ?>');"><i class="material-icons" data-target="#myModalDelete"  data-toggle="modal"
                    >close</i></button>`**

Comment: @A.Cedano   Si, pero lo que pasa es que no se ejecuta la funcion para eliminar el registro

Comment: No me queda claro si corregiste el error que mencionas más arriba en comentario. Pon un `alert` para probar primero si la función se está llamando o no.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya le puse un alert pero no me aparece nada, creo que no estoy llamando el archivo php, que es donde llamo a mi funcion no se en que parte hacerlo